# How to show multiple category in detail view django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm working on a Django blog, and having implemented category for detail page. I've stumbled upon an issue.

I want to display some categories of a product by using many to many field, I use the following code.

This my **model.py** file

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myshop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myshop:product_detail', args=[self.slug])
```

This is **views.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product

# Create your views here.

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})

def product_detail(request, product_slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug, available=True)
    category = product.category.filter(is_active=True)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product}, {'category': category})
```

and this is for **detail.html** page file

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.title }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="product-detail">
        <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
        <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
        {% for category in category %}<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <p class="price">${{ product.price }}</p>
            {{ product.description|linebreaks }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I followed the tutorial from Django by Example book.

in the book includes a code to display just one category of each product with the following code

```
<a href="{{ product.category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.
category }}</a>
```

and I change it to code like above in **detail.html** file.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
{% for category in product.category.all %}
   <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```